# Query update issue, it updates only the first match sqlserver2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, update

I'm trying to transfer part of data "ID" from table1 to table2, you may ask why doesn't table2 have the all the data. Answer is simple the data is generated by a program which doesn't contain all the data I'd like to be logged. I'm trying to import it from table1 instead. By default column 'id' didn't exist in table2.

Example:
Table1

```
user_id | date(item created)      | type | ID |
1         2023-05-18 21:50:43.357   15     62
1         2023-05-28 21:50:43.357   15     63
```

table2

```
user_id | type | ID | date(time of transaction) |
 1        15     x     2023-05-28 21:50:43.357 
 1        15     x     2023-05-28 21:50:43.357
```

Table2 can have multiple items transacted at the same time. That's the stem of the issue.
Default value of 'ID' in table2 is '0'. Maximum amount of transaction is '30' at once.
The issue isn't fetching the data from table 1, its the input into table 2:

Result of what I've tried.

```
user_id | type | ID | date(time of transaction) |
 1        15     62     2023-05-28 21:50:43.357 
 1        15     62     2023-05-28 21:50:43.357
```

What I've tried:

```
update x
set x.id=y.id
from table2 as x
inner join table2 as y on x.type=y.type
--inner join table2 as m on m.date=x.date 
where x.id=0
```

Also:

```
  WITH toUpdate AS
    (
       SELECT id, type,user_id,date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) AS RowNumber
       FROM table2
    ) 
    UPDATE toUpdate 
    SET toUpdate.id = t1.id 
    FROM table1 t1 
    INNER JOIN toUpdate ON t1.type = toUpdate.type and t1.char_id=toUpdate.user_id
    AND RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 30
```

Goal:
I need this solved as proof of concept since I don't know how to do it properly. Basically I want to filter results from table1(ID) and then replace them into table2 (ID). Or look it like this x user_id has y of type records, but table 2 transaction has z(y>z number of records) I'd expect it to pick any of the y records and input them as "id" into table2 as long they are not the same record.

What I meant above:
table 1:

```
user_id | date(item created)      | type | ID(y=4) |
1         2023-05-17 21:50:43.357   15     62
1         2023-05-18 21:50:43.357   15     63
1         2023-05-19 21:50:43.357   15     64
1         2023-05-20 21:50:43.357   15     65
```

Desired result:
Table 2:

```
user_id | type | ID(z=2) | date(time of transaction) |
 1        15     62     2023-05-17 21:50:43.357 
 1        15     63     2023-05-18 21:50:43.357
```

Comment: The query you tried doesn't work logically though, and here's why: Every row in your example, in **both** tables, has the same `type`, which causes a Cartesian product of rows. How do you decide which row in `table2` gets which `ID` value from `Table1`? Because the key of your `JOIN`'s `ON` clause is not unique (and there's no discernible one from your example) it's not possible to provide an answer currently. Are there other fields in the tables that can be used to uniquely tie them together or do you just not care which row gets set to which `ID`?

Comment: My thought process is:
Table1 returns 2 results which fit the criteria example 'user_id' has 2 items which are the same 'type' as table 2 the goal is just search locate results and then just drop the 'ids" into table 2. No I don't care which 'id' goes to which row I'd tinker with it and bind it somehow so it makes logical sense, but currently this is step 1 of the problem.